# Using powerBI I want to create a column based on values in 3 different columns and fitler if a 4th column is X

Tags: powerbi

I am fairly new to power bi, and I have and excel sheet with 3 rows of data with differing reasons for return I want to work out the most common reason but only if a 4th column (queried) is no

Please find the mark up table below

| Date | COLCO Code | COLCO | Customer Name | Masked Pan | Reason 1 validated | Reason 2 validated | Reason 3 validated | Delco(s) | Fraudulent Sites | Fraud Status | Analyst | Alert Priority | Rules Broken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2023 | 13 | France | GSBDD TOULOUSE_0904 | 707713 0904 | Temp card block | Excessive violation | EUR, | 017700, 067700, | Yes | Max | 751 | 13_LECLERC_HOT, 13_E.LECLERCV3, 13_SR12_SEPT19V4, 13_FDA_INTHOTV14, 13_CRT_EVEV2, 13_APML_13349, 13_CRT_XS, |  |
| 01/11/2023 | 53 | South Africa | LUSH REMOVALS AND STORAGE_1195 | 705553 1195 | Increased usage | Suspect Odometer | Late night/early morning usage | 9235, | No | Angita | 120 | 53_2D_INTERVAL, 53_30H_2STSV3, 53_HIGHVOL_1D |  |
| 01/11/2023 | 13 | France | RADIUS BUSINESS_5585 | 700213 5585 | Temp card block | Declined transactions | Empty uplift | FRA, CHE, | 1475, 0000, | No | Max | 30 | 13_EXTERNAL_58 |
| 01/11/2023 | 8 | Austria | LKW WALTER INT_0074 | 707708 0074 | Temp card block | Increased usage | Change in Product code | EUR, | RO0001000000000, | No | Angita | 30 | 08_VIGNETTES |
| 01/11/2023 | 22 | Sweden | MATS ÖSTERVALLS FLYGFRAKT_1145 | 707722 1145 | Temp card block | Change in product | Increased usage | EUR, | 82762276899128, | No | Angita | 60 | 22_014_BEL_EURV2, 22_CNP_TOLL2V2 |
| 01/11/2023 | 27 | Lithuania | UAB MTF_0440 | 707727 0440 | Suspicious Activity |  | FRA, | 3566, | No | Max | 0 | Stolen Card Script |  |
| 01/11/2023 | 53 | South Africa | POTTAS FAMILIE_7670 | 707753 7670 | Not regular site | Late night/early morning usage | ZAF, | 2009, | No | Angita | 42 | 53_SR_SEPT19V8 |  |
| 01/11/2023 | 9 | Belgium | DIESEL CARD BELGIUM_7616 | 700209 7616 | Temp card block | Increased usage | Empty uplift | EUR, BEL, | 1751947056, 0878, 0535, | No | Angita | 60 | 09_30H_3STS |
| 02/11/2023 | 21 | Spain | SC TRANS_8053 | 700221 8053 | Hotspot | Multiple sites | Increased usage | FRA, | 3030, 3335, | No | Max | 143 | 21_FDA_FRAHOTV12, 21_FLT_MORNINGV7 |
| 02/11/2023 | 13 | France | M PLUS MATERIAUX_0022 | 707713 0022 | Suspicious Activity |  | EUR, | 1854527250, | No | Max | 0 | V2 Skim script |  |

I want a new table that just shows the combined output of Rason 1 validated, Reason 2 and Reason 3 - where fraud status = Yes

Comment: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77777685/edit) and include a sample table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) and another with the desired result.

Comment: Done thanks for adding the link to the markdown format I will use this moving forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking for a Calculated Column (DAX) similar to:

```
My new column =
  var combined =
    [Reason 1 validated] & ", " & 
    [Reason 2 validated] & ", " &
    [Reason 3 validated]

  return IF([Fraud Status] = "Yes", combined )
```

You can also perform the same in PowerQuery via a Custom Column and its calculation will be very similar to the above.